# jsoup getElements MatchingOwn Text(its single method spilited limitation) example identifying html element

Tags: java, jsoup

Can any one help me with example using `getElementsMatchingOwnText` in jsoup to identify the exact element in html page, there could two text like status, new status the method should status is passed as parameter not new status if it occurs first.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your input html?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need?

**Example html:**

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p>new status</p>
  <p>status</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Example:**

```
    Document doc = ...

    for( Element element : doc.getElementsMatchingOwnText("(?i)^status$") )
    {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
<p>status</p>
```

*Alternative using [Jsoup Selector API](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax):*

```
for( Element element : doc.select("p:matchesOwn((?i)^status$)") )
```

Comment: without more info from the asker, this seems to be the answer. have an upvote. :) EDIT: I say without more info to mean that unless he/she clarifies that this is what they needed.